# Rejected connection: Transport(handshake was not a GET request)

Tags: nodes, substrate-node

When I start my node in the M2, it is continuously showing this error

.[image]

Comment: Did you change any code in the networking layer?

Answer (score -2):

This error indicates that there was an issue during the initial connection handshake process.

The handshake between the client and the server typically involves an exchange of information to establish a secure and valid connection. In

Comment: This is an incomplete answer, please edit or I will have to flag it.